# Please rename [xperia-play] to [sony-ericsson-xperia-play]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

To match our convention of `manufacturer-model` tags, please rename [xperia-play](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xperia-play) to [sony-ericsson-xperia-play](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sony-ericsson-xperia-play) and make the former a synonym of the latter.

In the event that the proposed tag name is too long, I suggest [sony-xperia-play](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sony-xperia-play). Sony and Ericsson have ended their manufacturing partnership and Sony is keeping the Xperia name. (Otherwise, please use `sony-xperia-play` as a synonym.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done.

Comment: Thanks, but you appear to have missed the [tag:xperia-play] synonym.

Comment: @AlEverett: Oops, you're right. I synonymized `sony-xperia-play` but not `xperia-play`. Both should be synonyms now.